# php unzip remote file

Tags: php, file, unzip

I need to unzip file, witch is in remote http server. And I have a code

```
<?php
$path = "http://mydomain.com/zipfile.zip";
$zip = new ZipArchive;
if ($zip->open($path, ZIPARCHIVE::CREATE) === TRUE) 
{
  $zip->extractTo('zip/');
  $zip->close();
  echo "ok';
} 
else 
{
  echo 'failed';
}
?>
```

The result after execution is "ok", but file did'n extract. Where can be problem?
P.S. in archive is only one .csv file

Answer (score 0):

It seems it unzipped the file in your local machine instead, because you're executing this php locally.  You probably will find this file in your PHP temp folder.

If you want it working on server, you should place this file on the server (let's say you call it unzip_file.php), change the $path to absolute path (something like /my/path/zipfile.zip).

You could download it straightway using php headers:

```
header('Content-Disposition:attachment; filename="' . $sFilename . '"');
```

Call this program instead: http://mydomain.com/unzip_file.php